# TCL: convert negative integer to hexadecimal?

Tags: format, hex, tcl, signed

I want to convert signed integer to 32-bit hexadecimal.
The following works fine for positive integer:

```
format %.8x $the_decimal_value
```

But for negative integer, I got 64-bit hexadecimal.
For example, `99` is converted to `00000063`, but `-81` is converted to `ffffffffffffffaf`.

Anyone know how to get 32-bit hexadecimal from a negative integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
% set num -81
% format 0x%.8x [expr {$num & 0xFFFFFFFF}]
0xffffffaf
```

The only hint in the docs I can find is [this](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/binary.htm#M42).